# That's almost Lisp!

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, lisp

### Challenge

Your challenge is to design an interpreter for a lisp-like language, which will from hence forth be coined: *GLisp*. The program code for *GLisp* will consist of an arbitrary amount of nested expressions denoted by brackets, in the following form:

```
(func arg1 arg2 ...)
```

Note that the interpreter must allow for extraneous whitespace characters before and after brackets, functions, and arguments.

### Types

You will implement four types, Integer, List, Boolean, and Function. Integers and Boolean values can be explicitly inserted into source code with their own syntax. Your interpreter must assume that a run of numeric characters denotes an Integer (you do not have to implement a syntax to explicitly insert negative integers). Your interpreter must also assume that `true` and `false` are designated Boolean values. Functions can not be explicitly defined by the user, and will always return a single value (a List of any length counts as a single value).

### Functions

The following functions are required to be implemented, and are in the format ***Function***, Arity. If an Arity `n` is proceeded by a plus sign, then that denotes `n` or more arguments. You may assume that all arguments given to a function are of the same type, unless specificed otherwise. You may also assume that if no behaviour is specified for a certian type, then you may assume that no argument of that function will ever be of that type. Arguments will be referred to as in the following diagram:

`(func argument1 argument2 ... argumentn)`

- **+**, 2+

  - If all arguments are of the type *Integer*, you must return the sum of the arguments
  - If all arguments are of the type *List*, you must return the concatenation of the arguments in ascending order (`arg1+arg2+ ...`)
  - If all arguments are of the type *Boolean*, you must return the logical All of the sequence of arguments
  - `(+ 1 2 3 4 5)  -> 15`
  - `(+ (list 1 2) (list 3 4))  -> (list 1 2 3 4)`
  - `(+ true true true)  -> true`
- **-**, 2+

  - If all arguments are of the type *Integer*, you must return the difference of the arguments (`arg1-arg2- ...`)
  - If all arguments are of the type *Boolean*, you  must return the logical Any of the sequence of arguments
  - `(- 8 4 3)  -> 1`
  - `(- 0 123)  -> -123`
  - `(- true false false true false)  -> true`
- *****, 2+

  - If all arguments are of type *Integer*, you must return the product of the arguments
  - If one argument is of type *List* and the other is of type *Integer* (you may assume that these will only be the only arguments given), you must return a new **List** with the items in `arg1` repeated `arg2` times.
  - `(* 1 2 3 4 5)  -> 120`
  - `(* (list 1 2 3) 2)  -> (list 1 2 3 1 2 3)`
- **/**, 2+

  - If all arguments are of the type *Integer*, you must return the quotient of the arguments (`arg/arg2/ ...`) (you may assume that division is done sequentially, and that the decimal portion at every step is truncated)
  - If one argument is of type *List* and the other is of type *Function*, then you must return the resulting *List* after `arg2` has been mapped over every value
  - `(/ 100 10 3)  -> 3`
  - `(/ (list 1 2 3) inc)  -> (list 2 3 4)`
- **%**, 2

  - If all arguments are of the type *Integer*, you must return the modulus of the arguments
  - `(% 4 2)  -> 0`
- **=**, 2+

  - If **both** the type and value of all arguments is the same, you must return true. Otherwise, return false.
  - `(= 0 0 0)  -> true`
  - `(= 0 false (list))  -> false`
- **list**, 0+

  - You must return a list of all arguments, regardless of type. If no arguments are given, then you must return an empty list
  - `(list 3 4 (list 5))  -> (list 3 4 (list 5))`
- **inc**, 1

  - If argument is of type *Integer*, you must return the *Integer* incremented by one
  - If argument is of type *List*, you must return the *List* rotated clockwise a single rotation
  - `(inc 1)  -> 2`
  - `(inc (list 1 2 3))  -> (list 3 1 2)`
- **dec**, 1

  - If argument is of type *Integer*, you must return the *Integer* decremented by one
  - If argument is of type *List*, you must return the *List* rotated counter-clockwise a single rotation
  - `(dec 1)  -> 0`
  - `(dec (list 1 2 3)) -> (list 2 3 1)`
- **if**, 3

  - If given **three** arguments of any type: If the truth value of `arg1` is true, return `arg2`, else return `arg3`
  - `(if (not (list 1)) 8 false)  -> false`
- **not**, 1

  - If given an argument of any type, if the truth value of `arg1` is False, return `true`, else return `false`.
  - `(not (list))  -> true`
- **len**, 1

  - If given an argument of type *List*, return the length of `arg1`
  - `(len (list 4 2 true (list 3) (list)))  -> 5`

Truth table:
`0, (list), false  -> false`, where `(list)` denotes an empty list. Everything else is `true`.

Your interpreter can either be a full program that reads the source input from stdin or a file, or a function which takes the source as a string and returns the output value.

If choosing the former, the output for *Integers* is simply numbers, for *Booleans* is `true` or `false`, and for lists is a space separated sequence of values enclosed in brackets (eg. `(1 2 3 4 (5 6 7))` denotes `(list 1 2 3 4 (list 5 6 7))`).

If choosing the latter, the value must be returned in the implementation language's corresponding type, or, if no similar type exists, a custom type. *Lists* can be returned as Arrays or Vectors if the language doesn't have a *List* type, *Booleans* should be returned as a Boolean type in the language, or a custom type if the language does not support them.

### Test cases

```
(list 1 2 3 (list 4 5 true))  -> (1 2 3 (4 5 true))
(/ 4000 (+ 1 2 3 4 (* 5 8)))  -> 80
(+ (not (- (len (list 5 6 7)) (/ 10 3))) true)  -> true
(if (           len (list )  ) 4 (if    (+ (= 8 8    8) (not (list 4))) 8 5))  -> 5
```

### Clarifications

- Your interpreter may deal with invalid input in any way you choose, but it **must not** throw an exception (though, it may print an error message and exit smoothly)
- Functions will always evaluate arguments left to right
- Invalid input is any input which is syntactically incorrect. This includes, but is not limited to, mismatched brackets, division by zero, and partially applied functions (unless going for the bonus)
- For `=`, if any of the values are different **or** any of the types are different, return `false`

### Bonuses

- **Score * 0.8** if you support partially applied functions. For example, `((+ 2) 3)` would be the same as `(+ 2 3)`, but allows for things such as `(/ (list 1 2 3) (+ 2))`. You may assume that a function is partially applied if it receives less than its minimum number of arguments
- **Score * 0.85** if you do not evaluate the arguments applied to `if` unless they are going to be returned

This is code-golf, so the interpreter with the lowest byte count wins!

Comment: How does one interpret `(if (not (array 1)) 8 false) -> false`?

Comment: @feersum good catch, is supposed to be 8.

Comment: I was wondering more about the undefined term `array`, and how the truth value of anything other than a boolean is determined.

Comment: @feersum `array` is also my sleep deprivation showing, and the truth table is below the functions.

Comment: How should we evaluate `(+ 3 (if false 5))`? Generally speaking, what really is "returning nothing"? You didn't specify any unit type to be retuned

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the last part. For example, do we return true/false as strings or as our language's corresponding bools?

Comment: also, is `%` applied left-to-right or right-to-left?

Comment: 1. Why is `(+ bool bool...)` logical AND and `(- bool bool...)` logical OR? The standard ring notation would use `+` for OR and `*` for AND. 2. Is "invalid input" intended to cover cases like `(/ 2 0)` which are syntactically correct? 3. For `=`, if the values are not all the same, should it return `false`? 4. The definition of `not` appears to be backwards. 5. What are the tokens? You say that the interpreter must handle extra whitespace, but you don't say what whitespace it can rely on. For complex questions like this, you really should use the sandbox so that the spec can be checked.

Comment: @proudhaskeller (+ 3 (if false 5)) is the same as (+ 3), which you may treat as invalid output. % is applied left to right.

Comment: @Sp3000 If you're printing the output to stdout, you return the strings. Otherwise, you return it in your language's boolean type.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1) Will change. 2) Yes, and cases in which you may have mismatched brackets, or a value being used as a function, etc. 3) Yes 4) Fixed 5) whitespace between brackets, functions, and arguments. and I agree, I should have used the sandbox.

Comment: it isn't clear how partial application should work: is `((+ 2 3) 4)` equal to `9` or an error? Notably, for var-arg functions, it isn't clear when one should consider the application partial. It gets even muddier with things like `((if true (+ 2 3) (- 5)) 4)`

Comment: @MtnViewMark it is an error. If a function is given less than its minimum number of arguments, then it is partially applied

Comment: The example for `if` is wrong: `(not (list 1))` is `false`, so the expected answer is `false`, not `8`.

Comment: Can someone clarify what kind of "crash" isn't allowed? The way it's worded currently suggests to me that a language exception isn't allowed, but a custom exception is. Which seems a bit silly because, for instance, one could just rebrand any language exception as a "custom" exception by catching and rethrowing it.

Comment: @Runer112 rephrased.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <strike>1370</strike> <strike>1263</strike> <strike>1179</strike> <strike>1128</strike> <strike>1163</strike> <strike>1107</strike> 1084 bytes * 0.8 * 0.85 = 737.12

```
import Text.Parsec
data V=I Int|L[V]|T|F|P[V]|X|A|S|M|D|U|E|Q|J|K|C|N|W deriving Eq
m Q=0;m C=3;m f|f`elem`[J,K,N,W]=1;m _=2
l=length
x v=[n|I n<-v]
y v=[l|L l<-v]
z v=[0<1|T<-v]++[1<0|F<-v]
(&)f=l.f>>=(.l).(==)
b a|a=T|0<1=F
s(I n)=show n
s(L v)='(':tail(v>>=(' ':).s)++")"
s T=d!!0;s F=d!!1;s _="error"
i(L v)=e$i%v
i v=v
e(P v:a)=e$v++a
e(f:a)|m f>l a=P(f:a)
e(A:a)|x&a=I$sum$x a|y&a=L$concat$y a|z&a=b$and$z a
e(S:a)|x&a=I$f$x a|z&a=b$or$z a
e(M:a)|x&a=I$product$x a
e[M,v,I n]=e$A:replicate n v
e(D:a)|x&a=I$v$x a
e[D,L v,f]=L$map(\a->e[f,a])v
e[U,I a,I b]=I$a`mod`b
e(E:a:v)=b$all(==a)v
e(Q:a)=L a
e[J,I a]=I$a+1
e[J,L[]]=L[]
e[J,L v]=L$last v:init v
e[K,I a]=I$a-1
e[K,L v]=L$drop 1 v++take 1 v
e[C,a,b,c]|a`elem`[I 0,L[],F]=c|0<1=b
e[N,a]=e[C,a,F,T]
e[W,L v]=I$l v
e _=X
f(a:b)=a-sum b
v(a:b)=foldl div a b
(%)f=fmap f
p=k$choice$try%([(I .read)%many1 digit,L%between(w"(")(k$w")")(many$try p)]++zipWith((.return).(>>).w)d[T,F,A,S,M,D,U,E,Q,J,K,C,N,W])
k=(spaces>>)
w=string
d=words"true false + - * / % = list inc dec if not len"
g=either show(s.i).parse p""
main=interact g
```

Full program, reading `stdin` and writing to `stdout`. `g` is the function version, as well.

Implements both partial functions, and lazy evaluation of `if`.

Sample runs (of the function version):

```
λ: g "(list 1 2 3 (list 4 5 true))"
(1 2 3 (4 5 true))

λ: g "(/ 4000 (+ 1 2 3 4 (* 5 8)))"
80

λ: g "(+ (not (- (len (list 5 6 7)) (/ 10 3))) true)"
true

λ: g "(if (           len (list )  ) 4 (if    (+ (= 8 8    8) (not (list 4))) 8 5))"
5

λ: g "(if false (/ 1 0) 5)"
5

λ: g "((+ 2) 3)"
5

λ: g "(/ (list 1 2 3) (+ 2))"
(3 4 5)
```

Now has all unit tests from the description:

```
λ: runTests 
passed: g "(+ 1 2 3 4 5)" ==> 15
passed: g "(+ (list 1 2) (list 3 4))" ==> (1 2 3 4)
passed: g "(+ true true true)" ==> true
passed: g "(- 8 4 3)" ==> 1
passed: g "(- 0 123)" ==> -123
passed: g "(- true false false true false)" ==> true
passed: g "(* 1 2 3 4 5)" ==> 120
passed: g "(* (list 1 2 3) 2)" ==> (1 2 3 1 2 3)
passed: g "(/ 100 10 3)" ==> 3
passed: g "(/ (list 1 2 3) inc)" ==> (2 3 4)
passed: g "(% 4 2)" ==> 0
passed: g "(= 0 0 0)" ==> true
passed: g "(= 0 false (list))" ==> false
passed: g "(list 3 4 (list 5))" ==> (3 4 (5))
passed: g "(inc 1)" ==> 2
passed: g "(inc (list 1 2 3))" ==> (3 1 2)
passed: g "(dec 1)" ==> 0
passed: g "(dec (list 1 2 3))" ==> (2 3 1)
passed: g "(if (not (list 1)) 8 9)" ==> 9
passed: g "(not (list))" ==> true
passed: g "(len (list 4 2 true (list 3) (list)))" ==> 5
passed: g "(list 1 2 3 (list 4 5 true))" ==> (1 2 3 (4 5 true))
passed: g "(/ 4000 (+ 1 2 3 4 (* 5 8)))" ==> 80
passed: g "(+ (not (- (len (list 5 6 7)) (/ 10 3))) true)" ==> true
passed: g "(if (           len (list )  ) 4 (if    (+ (= 8 8    8) (not (list 4))) 8 5))" ==> 5
passed: g "(if false (/ 1 0) 5)" ==> 5
passed: g "((+ 2) 3)" ==> 5
passed: g "(/ (list 1 2 3) (+ 2))" ==> (3 4 5)
```

Comment: b the cases  `e[K,L _]` you could use `drop 1 ` as a safe version of `tail` and use `take` for a safe version of `head` joining the two definitions of `e[K,L _]`

Comment: you can use the function `notElem` .another tip: you can do `s=string` and use it instead of both `string` and `char` (`s"C"` vs. `char 'C'`). another tip: use guards instead of `if`s

Comment: Another thing I thought of: you can encode `Maybe` values by lists. `Nothing` is `[]` and `Just x` is `[x]`. This gets rid of the long constructors and adds some more functionalities: `if p then Just x else Nothing` is `[x|p]`, `(==Nothing)` is `null`, the list monad becomes the same as the maybe monad, and so forth.

Comment: @proudhaskeller Thanks, all applied!

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 1417 * 0.8 * 0.85 = 963.56

```py
from operator import*
A=type;K="list"
def E():print"E";exit()
def R(G):
 len(G)or E();T=G.pop(0);L=[]
 if"("==T:
  G or E()
  while")"!=G[0]:L+=[R(G)];G or E()
  G.pop(0);return L
 if")"==T:E()
 try:
  x=eval(T.title())
  if Q(x)<2:return x
  E()
 except:return T
H="+ - * / = % if inc dec not len"
Z=lambda y:lambda x:reduce(y,x)
D=dict(zip(H.split(),[[sum,any,0,lambda x:sum((y[1:]for y in x),[K])],[Z(sub)],[Z(mul),all,0,lambda x:x[0][:1]+x[0][1:]*x[1]],[Z(div),lambda x:[K]+map(lambda z:S([x[1],z]if Q(x[1])==2else x[1]+[z]),x[0][1:])],[lambda x:len(set(map(str,x)))<2]*6,[lambda x:x[0]%x[1]],[lambda x:S(x[2])if S(x[0])in[0,[K]]else S(x[1])]*6,[lambda x:x[0]+1,0,0,lambda x:x[0][:1]+x[0][-1:]+x[0][1:-1]],[lambda x:x[0]-1,0,0,lambda x:x[0][:1]+x[0][2:]+[x[0][1]]],[lambda x:x[0]in[0,[K]]]*6,[0]*3+[lambda x:len(x)-1]]))
H=H[:15]+H+" if"
def Q(x):
 t=A(x);w=int,bool,str
 if t in w:return w.index(t)
 if t==list and x:return 5-(2*(x[0]==K)+(str==A(x[0])and len(x)<H.count(x[0])+1))
 E()
def S(G):
 if Q(G)<2:return G
 G or E();c=G[0];r=G[1:];c==K or r or E()
 if c!="if":r=[x if Q(x)in{2,4}else S(x)for x in r]
 if c==K:return[c]+r
 k=map(Q,r);m=min(k);M=max(k);v=[m,[-1,3][{m,M}=={4,5}]][m!=M]
 try:return D[c][v](r)
 except:E()
def C(x):return"(%s)"%" ".join(map(C,x))if A(x)==list else str(x).lower()
def I(G):
 for c in"+-*/%=()":G=G.replace(c," %s "%c)
 return C(S(R(G.strip().split())))
print I(raw_input())
```

Complete overhaul. If you want to see the previous versions, check out the [edit history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/43253/3).

There's a lot more to be golfed. I'm slowly working on it.

With zlib/base64 we get **1093 * 0.8 * 0.85 = 743.24**:

```py
import base64,zlib
exec zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode("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"))
```

*Note: If you see my score going up, it's probably because I found a few bugs*

Comment: more of a code challenge than a code golf but still,  4872*0.8=3897,6

Answer (score 5):

## Common Lisp, 868 bytes * 0.85 = 737.8

Is it cheating to implement Lisp with Lisp? Lots to optimize here, still.

```
(SETF (READTABLE-CASE *READTABLE*) :PRESERVE)(PRINC(LABELS((B(X)(FIND X'(true false)))(R(X)(IF X'true'false))(V(X)(MEMBER X'(0()false)))(A(&REST X)(R(NOTANY #'V X)))(O(&REST X)(R(NOTEVERY #'V X)))(E(X &KEY N)(IF(LISTP X)(ECASE(FIRST X)(+(APPLY(IF(EVERY'NUMBERP #1=(MAPCAR(IF N #'IDENTITY #'E)(CDR X)))'+(IF(EVERY'LISTP #1#)'APPEND #'A))#1#))(-(APPLY(IF(EVERY'NUMBERP #1#)'- #'O)#1#))(*(IF(LISTP #2=(CAR #1#))(LOOP FOR I TO(1-(CADR #1#))APPEND #2#)(APPLY'* #1#)))(/(IF(LISTP #2#)(LOOP FOR I IN #2#COLLECT(E `(,(CADR #1#),I):N T))(REDUCE'FLOOR #1#)))(%(APPLY'MOD #1#))(=(R(LOOP FOR I IN(CDR #1#)ALWAYS(EQUAL I #2#))))(list #1#)(inc(IF(LISTP #2#)(APPEND(LAST #2#)(BUTLAST #2#))(1+ #2#)))(dec(IF(LISTP #2#)(APPEND(CDR #2#)`(,(FIRST #2#)))(1- #2#)))(if(IF(V(E(CADR X)))(E(CADDDR X))(E(CADDR X))))(not(R(V #2#)))(len(LENGTH #2#)))X)))(OR(IGNORE-ERRORS(OR(E(READ))"()")):E))
```

Prints out an E in case of an error in input. Sample runs:

```
$ sbcl --script glisp.lisp
(list 1 2 3 (list 4 5 true))
(1 2 3 (4 5 true))

$ sbcl --script glisp.lisp
(/ 4000 (+ 1 2 3 4 (* 5 8)))
80

$ sbcl --script glisp.lisp
(+ (not (- (len (list 5 6 7)) (/ 10 3))) true)
true

$ sbcl --script glisp.lisp
(if (           len (list )  ) 4 (if    (+ (= 8 8    8) (not (list 4))) 8 5))
5

$ sbcl --script glisp.lisp
(this is an error)
E

$ sbcl --script glisp.lisp
(if (% 4 2) (this is an error) 42)
42
```

Comment: as long as it isn't a kind of eval function...

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 972

```
r=fst.f
f('(':s)|(f:a,b)<-g s=(f%filter(/="")a,b)
f s=span(`notElem`" ()")s
j=dropWhile(==' ')
g""=([],"")
g s|')':l<-r=([x],l)|(y,t)<-g$j r=(x:y,t)where(x,r)=f$j s
"%"%c=show$foldr(mod.read)(maxBound::Int)c
"+"%c|t(c!!0)<1="(list "++tail(c>>=(' ':).drop 6.init)++")"|t(c!!0)<2=show$sum$map read c|0<1=i$all((=='t').head)c
"-"%c|t(c!!0)<2=show$foldl1(-)$map read c|0<1=i$any((=='t').head)c
"*"%c=fst$f$"(+ "++unwords([1..read$last c]>>init c)++")"
"="%c=i$all(==c!!0)c
"/"%c|t(c!!0)<1,[a,b]<-c="list"%map(\x->b%[x])(fst$g$drop 6 a)|0<1=show$foldl1 div$map read c
"if"%[p,a,b]|elem p["0","()","false"]=b|0<1=a
"list"%c="(list "++unwords c++")"
"len"%[c]=show$length(words c)-1
"inc"%[c]|t c>0=show$read c+1|([],_)<-g$drop 6 c="(list)"|(x,_)<-g$drop 6 c="list"%(last x:init x)
"dec"%[c]|t c<1,(x,_)<-g$drop 6 c="list"%(drop 1 x++take 1 x)|0<1=show$read c-1
"not"%[c]="if"%[c,"false","true"]
s%c="?"
i p|p="true"|0<1="false"
t('(':_)=0
t(c:s)|c<':',c>'/'=1|elem c"th"=2
t _=3
```

quite a hacky solution. this stores everything as strings in output-ready form - their types can be distinguished by their first letter - `0..9` for numbers, `(` for  lists, `t` or `f` for booleans, and everything else for functions.

to run use the `r` function.